# UnitOfWork logs

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, unit-of-work

In my java eclipselink web application I have seen some logs related to UnitOfWork

```
15:45:24.140 [qtp55821173-112] WARN  o.e.persistence.logging.default - 2013-03-27 15:45:24.14--UnitOfWork(2111553158)--
15:46:22.953 [qtp55821173-24] WARN  o.e.persistence.logging.default - 2013-03-27 15:46:22.952--UnitOfWork(1041525431)--
15:46:24.568 [qtp55821173-55] WARN  o.e.persistence.logging.default - 2013-03-27 15:46:24.567--UnitOfWork(1631959950)--
15:46:26.127 [qtp55821173-20] WARN  o.e.persistence.logging.default - 2013-03-27 15:46:26.127--UnitOfWork(272775397)--
```

What are these log statements meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of the EclipseLink JPA framework, you can find more information on it [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/ORMTransactions#Unit_Of_Work).

> A database transaction is a set of operations (create, read, update, or delete) that either succeed or fail as a single operation. The database discards, or rolls back, unsuccessful transactions, leaving the database in its original state. In EclipseLink, transactions are encapsulated by the Unit of Work object. Using the Unit of Work, you can transactionally modify objects directly or by way of a Java 2 Enterprise Edition (J2EE) external transaction controller such as the Java Transaction API (JTA).